# Requesting friends on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

Why can't I send a friend request on Facebook?

When I can see his profile, and I can send a message, why is the (faded) button there for sending a friend request, but doesn't let me send one?

Answer (score 2):

People can select the audience they want to receive friend requests from in their settings. If you know this person in real life, you might consider sending them a message and asking them to friend you.

See [Why can't I add someone as a friend?](https://www.facebook.com/help/211926158839933)

Other thing is friend request button appearing/disappearing also depend on denied friend request or blocking then unblocking a user.